# Angular How to watch for changes on a Scope variable

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, scope

I'm trying to build my own cart system in Angular and Node. My controller handles both user carts in a mongo database and carts in local storage (if a user doesn't have an account). Right now I've created a way for my cart controller to remove a cart item from both local storage and the database. My angular view watches the object.

```
$scope.lineItems
```

For populating the cart with items. Right now I can successfully get the updated cart but I need to refresh my page. What would be the best way to update the scope via triggering a function that updates the scope?

Code:

```
if ( token ) {
    var payload = authService.parseToken(token);
    dataService.getCart(payload._id).then(function (resolve){
      if (resolve.data){
        $scope.lineItems = resolve.data; 

        $scope.deleteLineItem = function(lineitem){
            dataService.deleteLineItem([lineitem.lineItemID, payload._id]);
        }
      }
    }, function(reason){
      console.log(reason);
    });
} else {
    if (dataService.retrieveLocal('localCart')){
        $scope.lineItems = dataService.retrieveLocal('localCart');

        $scope.deleteLineItem = function(lineitem){
            var cart = dataService.retrieveLocal('localCart');
            var updatedCart = cart.filter(function(item){
                if (lineitem.lineItemID != item.lineItemID){
                    return item
                }
            })
            dataService.storeToLocal('localCart', updatedCart);
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommand you not to use `AngularJS Watcher` due to heavy load cost, Generally in your app try to minimize your watchers(timers).
In addition in your case you don't need to use `watcher`, because when you're using `LocalStorage` there is no need to refresh the page in all browser tab again, In fact your cart items just watch your `$localStorage.lineItems` instead of $scope.lineItems and since $localStorage.lineItems was updated all browser tab will be updated automatically.
And in one tab you will have a trigger to start request and server-side processing based on a click event and so on, Then in response update your localStorage variable(`$localStorage.lineItems`), So your content will be  always updated.